# Can't set line color while drawing

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, lines, fragment-shader

In my application, I can't explicitly set the color of the lines that I draw, as they will either be black, or they mimic the color of the last object I have rendered in the scene.

This is quite a bit of a problem, because I want to put a grid at the center of my scene.

I render like this:

```
{
    shaderProgram.bind();
    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", qmat);
    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("texture", 0);

    for (int x = 0; x < tileCount; x++)
    {
        shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", tiles[x]->vertices.constData());
        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");
        shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("textureCoordinate", textureCoordinates.constData());
        shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tiles[x]->image.width(), tiles[x]->image.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tiles[x]->image.bits());
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tiles[x]->vertices.size());
    }

    //Draw Lines
    for (int x = -2000; x < 2000; x+=10)
    {
        glLineWidth(1);
        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex3f(x,0,2000);
        glVertex3f(x,0,-2000);
        glEnd();
    }

    shaderProgram.release();
}
```

Do I need to do anything to my fragment shader? I currently draw vertices of my own, so I don't know how to set it up to incorporate both colors and textures
My fragment shader is set up like this:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

in vec2 varyingTextureCoordinate;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragColor = texture2D(texture, varyingTextureCoordinate);
}
```

Comment: Some good techniques for debugging include (1) staring at the code and thinking, (2) using a debugger to see what's actually going on, (3) using trace output statements to get information about particular details, (4) explaining the code to someone else (if none available try to write about it), (5) writing small test programs where you have full control, (6) studying other examples of what you're trying to do, (7) checking bug reports and errata lists and so on, … ETC.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant insight. I've never done both individual line drawing **and** texturing triangles at the same time, all I can get is one or the other to work. There are no bugs, just a wrong result because I know I'm missing something, but I don't know what. But I thank you, because now I totally know what I'm missing...

Comment: Your shader gets the color from the texture. The `glColor3f()` call does not influence the color calculation in your fragment shader. The easiest solution is to use a different shader to draw the solid color lines.

Comment: If I load it just like the previous fragment shader, then how do I indicate that I want to use it? Do I have to unload the previous one?

Comment: Simply call `glUseProgram()` with the shader you want to use.

Comment: you may simply multiply texture color with `gl_Color` : `fragColor = gl_Color * texture2D(texture, varyingTextureCoordinate);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to actually start learning GLSL and write my own shaders instead of relying on the ones I was provided with during my first OpenGL tutorials.

As others have said, I needed to alter the way my fragment shader outputs the frag color, like multiplying it by a different color vector:

```
fragColor = color * texture2D(texture, varyingTextureCoordinate);
```

However, this code alone is problematic since color has to be a Vec4, and my textures don't have uniform alpha channels, and I don't have a replacement texture for my lines. 
The easy solution is to send the fragment shader a boolean as well, to check whether I want to just render my texture, or render a color:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform bool colors;
void main(void)
{
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(texture, varyingTextureCoordinate);   
    if (colors == true)
        fragColor = color;
    else
        fragColor = textureColor;
}
```

and during my paint function:

```
//Before Painting objects
shaderProgram.setUniformValue("colors", false);
shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("colors");
/*Draw Objects*/

shaderProgram.setUniformValue("colors", true);
shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("colors");
/*Draw Lines*/
```

Comment: It would also be possible to use a separate shader. However I didn't want to be flipping through multiple shaders during a single rendering call, when instead I can just do a single byte check.